# SIGABRT and corrupted double-linked list

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm working on a school project where I need to get info for a matrix from a file (height, width, cell status). Something like this:

```
30 40    /*height and width*/
3        /*nr of lines to read from the file*/
10 11 1  /*coordinates, and cell status (0,1,2)*/
10 12 1
10 13 2
```

And for some reason it keeps giving me SIGABRT in the debugger or corrupted double-linked list. I know that the code is not as perfect as it could be, but I started modifying it to see if I could find the problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int ***getFileLoad(char *fileName)
{
    char strLines[5], strColumns[5], strCells[5], strTemp[3];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, lines = 0, columns = 0, cells = 0, intTemp = 0;
    int ***array = NULL;
    FILE *file = NULL;

    file = fopen(fileName, "r"); /*opens file*/

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%s %s %s", &strLines, &strColumns, &strCells);
    lines = atoi(strLines);
    if (lines <= 0) /*lines*/
    {
        printf("Invalid value, lines!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    columns = atoi(strColumns);
    if (columns <= 0)  /*columns*/
    {
        printf("Invalid value, columns!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cells = atoi(strCells);
    if (cells <= 0)  /*cells*/
    {
        printf("Invalid value, cells!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    array = (int ***)malloc(sizeof(int **) * lines); /*allocating lines*/

    if (array == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)            /*allocating columns*/
    {
        array[i] = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * columns);

        if (array[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("No memory!");
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                free(array[j]);
            }
            free(array);
            array = NULL;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)            /*allocating nr of cells*/
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * cells);

            if (array[i][j] == NULL)
            {
                printf("No memory!");
                for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
                {
                    for (l = 0; l < j; l++)
                    {
                        free(array[k][l]);
                    }
                }

                for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
                {
                    free(array[k]);
                }
                free(array);
                array = NULL;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    array[0][0][0] = lines;
    array[0][0][1] = columns;
    array[0][0][2] = cells;

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)         /*nr arrays*/
    {
        for (j = 1; j < cells + 1; j++) /*nr cells*/
        {
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) /*values from file*/
            {
                if (k == 3)         /*getting to the next line*/
                {
                    intTemp = fgetc(file);
                    if (intTemp == '\n' || intTemp == EOF)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (intTemp != '\n' || intTemp != EOF)
                        {
                            intTemp = fgetc(file);
                            if (intTemp == '\n' || intTemp == EOF)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    fscanf(file, "%s", strTemp);

                    if (isdigit(strTemp))
                    {
                        intTemp = atoi(strTemp);
                        if (k == 0)         /*accepting lines with values between1->lines*/
                        {
                            if (!(intTemp >= 1 && intTemp < lines))
                            {
                                printf("Invalid value!");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array[i][j][k] = intTemp;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (k == 1)    /*accepting columns with values between 1->columns*/
                        {
                            if (!(intTemp >= 1 && intTemp < columns))
                            {
                                printf("Invalid value!");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array[i][j][k] = intTemp;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (k == 2)    /*accepting cells with values between 0->2*/
                        {
                            if (!(intTemp >= 0 && intTemp < 3))
                            {
                                printf("Invalid value!");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array[i][j][k] = intTemp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    intTemp = fgetc(file); /*checking for EOF*/

    if (intTemp != EOF)
    {
        printf("Impossible reading every value!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return array;
}
```

Comment: Beware of ['Three-Star Programming/Programmers'](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Please tell us more about what you have found in the debugger. For example, the debugger should tell you which line of code the problem is detected on.

Comment: If you've been running it in the debugger (that's good), you must know where the SIGABRT occurs.  Your title mentions 'corrupted double-linked list', but there's no code here working with linked lists.  It probably means you're mishandling the allocated memory, writing out of bounds, and trampling over the control data that `malloc()` et al use to keep track of which memory is allocated and free.

Comment: Don't forget to end printing operations with a new line.  It's also good to include the value that you failed to convert in the error message and to print the error to standard error: `fprintf(stderr, "Invalid value '%s' for number of cells!\n", strCells);`.

Comment: The principal problem here is that you wrote one function when you should have written about ten.

Comment: I'm programing in CodeBlocks, I'm using the programs debuger, and it doesnt say much. It identifies malloc.c and abort.c.

Comment: when calling `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `malloc()` and family of functions, in C, do not cast the returned value.  the type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain

Comment: there are LOTS of logic errors in the posted code, here is one:  `fscanf(file, "%s", strTemp);  if (isdigit(strTemp))`  The code read a string (which it fails to limit the number of char read, so buffer overflow can occur, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event)  the tries to compare the `address` of the string with the values 0...9.  This will not work.   (in C, using the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array)

Comment: regarding this line: `for (j = 1; j < cells + 1; j++)` in C, array offsets start with 0 and continue to 'length of array -1'  so starting with offset 1 and continuing to the size of the array+1 will: 1) miss the first first entry in the array 2) access beyond the end of the upper bound of the array, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: this line: `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)` will result in the enclosed loop being executed once.   I would have expected the second parameter to be: `i<lines`

Comment: these lines: `                   if (intTemp == '\n' || intTemp == EOF)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }`  is just returning to the prior `for()` statement, when encountering EOF should have resulting in stopping all attempts to read more data elements

Comment: this line: `while (intTemp != '\n' || intTemp != EOF)` will always fail to perform the desired operation.  It is probably wrong overall, but if used should be: `while (intTemp != '\n' && intTemp != EOF)`  There are other other instances in the posted code of this kind of logic error.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic (I also use -std=c99 -Wconversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is the same as it usually is with these types of questions - you're making your task far too complicated for yourself, by:

- Stuffing too much in one huge function instead of breaking it up into digestible pieces
- Using clumsy file-reading functions like `fscanf()` and `fgetc()`
- Duplicating code, including error checking code which could be decanted to a separate function

all of which make it extremely difficult to keep track of what you're doing, because your huge function reads like spaghetti and you have no big-picture view of it. It becomes just a big mass of code, any of which could be wrong.

Here are some examples of actions which you can and should have separate functions for:

- Creating your matrix
- Destroying your matrix
- Setting the value of a matrix cell
- Getting the value of a matrix cell
- Getting a set of coordinates from a file
- Getting your dimensions from a file
- Getting the number of lines from the file

In addition, you should wrap related values up in data structures, such as the dimensions of your matrix (and those dimensions with the matrix data itself), and your coordinates.

Here's a quick example of a better way to write it. Look at the `main()` function, for instance, and see how much easier it is to follow. If your code is easy to follow and easy to read, then it's easy to maintain, and much easier to find (and avoid) bugs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024


/*  Holds dimensions for a matrix  */

struct dimensions {
    int lines;
    int columns;
    int cells;
};


/*  Holds a set of three-dimensional coordinates  */

struct coords {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};


/*  Holds a three-dimensional matrix  */

struct matrix {
    struct dimensions dim;
    int *** lines;
};

void * xmalloc(const size_t sz);
void * xcalloc(const size_t nmemb, const size_t size);
struct matrix * matrixCreate(struct dimensions * dim);
void matrixDestroy(struct matrix * matrix);
void matrixSet(struct matrix * matrix, struct coords coord, const int value);
int matrixGet(struct matrix * matrix, struct coords coord);
FILE * openDataFile(const char * filename);
void getLineFromFile(FILE * fp, char * buffer, const size_t length);
struct dimensions getDimensionsFromFile(FILE * fp);
struct coords getCoordsFromFile(FILE * fp);
void validateCoords(struct matrix * matrix, struct coords coords);
int getSingleIntegerLine(FILE * fp);

int main(void)
{
    /*  Set up matrix and data file  */

    FILE * fp = openDataFile("matrix.dat");
    struct dimensions dim = getDimensionsFromFile(fp);
    const int numLines = getSingleIntegerLine(fp);
    struct matrix * matrix = matrixCreate(&dim);


    /*  Populate matrix cells specified in file  */

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numLines; ++i ) {
        struct coords coords = getCoordsFromFile(fp);
        validateCoords(matrix, coords);
        matrixSet(matrix, coords, 1);
    }


    /*  Test and print the value of some matrix cells  */

    struct coords coords[6] = {
        {10, 11, 1},
        {10, 11, 2},
        {10, 12, 1},
        {10, 12, 2},
        {10, 13, 1},
        {10, 13, 2}
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i ) {
        const int value = matrixGet(matrix, coords[i]);
        printf("Value at %d, %d, %d: %d\n",
               coords[i].x, coords[i].y, coords[i].z, value);
    }


    /*  Clean up and exit  */

    matrixDestroy(matrix);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void * xmalloc(const size_t sz)
{
    void * p = malloc(sz);
    if ( !p ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

void * xcalloc(const size_t nmemb, const size_t size)
{
    void * p = calloc(nmemb, size);
    if ( !p ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

struct matrix * matrixCreate(struct dimensions * dim)
{
    int *** lines = xmalloc(dim->lines * sizeof *lines);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < dim->lines; ++i ) {
        int ** columns = xmalloc(dim->columns * sizeof *columns);
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < dim->columns; ++j ) {
            int * cells = xcalloc(dim->cells, sizeof *cells);
            columns[j] = cells;
        }
        lines[i] = columns;
    }

    struct matrix * matrix = xmalloc(sizeof *matrix);
    matrix->lines = lines;
    matrix->dim = *dim;
    return matrix;
}

void matrixDestroy(struct matrix * matrix)
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < matrix->dim.lines; ++i ) {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < matrix->dim.columns; ++j ) {
            free(matrix->lines[i][j]);
        }
        free(matrix->lines[i]);
    }
    free(matrix->lines);
    free(matrix);
}

void matrixSet(struct matrix * matrix, struct coords coords, const int value)
{
    matrix->lines[coords.x][coords.y][coords.z] = value;
}

int matrixGet(struct matrix * matrix, struct coords coords)
{
    return matrix->lines[coords.x][coords.y][coords.z];
}

FILE * openDataFile(const char * filename)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if ( !fp ) {
        perror("couldn't open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}

void getLineFromFile(FILE * fp, char * buffer, const size_t length)
{
    if ( !fgets(buffer, length, fp) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read dimensions from file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

struct dimensions getDimensionsFromFile(FILE * fp)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    getLineFromFile(fp, buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    struct dimensions dim;
    if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &dim.lines, &dim.columns) != 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read dimensions from file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    dim.cells = 3;
    return dim;
}

struct coords getCoordsFromFile(FILE * fp)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    getLineFromFile(fp, buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    struct coords coords;
    if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %d", &coords.x, &coords.y, &coords.z) != 3 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read coordinates from file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    return coords;
}

void validateCoords(struct matrix * matrix, struct coords coords)
{
    bool valid = true;

    if ( coords.x < 0 || coords.x >= matrix->dim.lines ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid x coordinate: %d\n", coords.x);
        valid = false;
    }

    if ( coords.y < 0 || coords.y >= matrix->dim.columns ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid y coordinate: %d\n", coords.y);
        valid = false;
    }

    if ( coords.z < 0 || coords.z >= matrix->dim.cells ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid z coordinate: %d\n", coords.z);
        valid = false;
    }

    if ( !valid ) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int getSingleIntegerLine(FILE * fp)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    getLineFromFile(fp, buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    int value;
    if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value) != 1 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read single value from file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    return value;
}
```

with output, using your example file:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./matrix
Value at 10, 11, 1: 1
Value at 10, 11, 2: 0
Value at 10, 12, 1: 1
Value at 10, 12, 2: 0
Value at 10, 13, 1: 0
Value at 10, 13, 2: 1
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: when a `malloc()` fails after part of the 3d matrix allocated, need to pass all the memory allocation pointers to `free()` before calling `exit()`  This kind of cleanup operation can be rather extensive, involved, so suggest a separate function to perform the cleanup and always call it before calling `exit()`

Comment: @user3629249: There's no need to do this on any modern multi-user operating system where such a program would be run.

Comment: if the program is going to exit right away,,,, then the OS can be given the extra work of cleaning up after sloppy code.  However, just because something 'can' be done (like the code not cleaning up after itself) does not mean that is how it should be done.  Good programming practice includes the code cleaning up after itself.  If a programmer uses such sloppy practices, then sooner or later they will write some program where the lack of cleanup will result in lost data, out of memory condition, etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you loop the variable j from 0 to 3 when the array it refers to i 3 in size. Maybe changning line 86 from:

```
for (j = 1; j<cells + 1; j++) {   /*nr cells*/
```

to:

```
for (j = 1; j<cells; j++) {   /*nr cells*/
```

will fix the problem.